# Closest element to subspace $S$ in Hilbert space has orthogonality

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

> Let $H$ be Hilbert space and $\left(\cdot,\cdot\right)$ be it's inner
>   product.
>
> And let $S$ be a closed subspace in $H$.
>
> If there is a closest element $g_{0}$ in $S$ to $f\in H$, I want to prove
>   $\left(f-g_{0},g\right)=0$ for any $g\in S$.

My attempt : By assumption, $\|f-g_{0}\|\leq\|f-g\|$ for all $g\in S$.
So 
$$
\|f-g_{0}\|^{2}\leq\|f-g\|^{2}.
$$
And I expand this. But there is nothing I can obtain. Anyone can help
me?

Comment: Try summing and subtracting g in the first norm, then expand the norm. The scalar product should pop up

Comment: @Harnak I tried that but I can't reach the goal. From your advice, I reached $\left(2f-g-g_{0},g-g_{0}\right)\leq0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, anoher way from your starting point. Denote $z=f-g_0$. Without loss of generality we can suppose that $ \left\|{g}\right\|=1$. We have $$\langle z,z\rangle=\left\|{z}\right\|^2\le\left\|{z-\alpha g}\right\|^2=\langle z-\alpha g,z-\alpha g\rangle\text{ for all }\alpha \text{ scalar}. $$
Symplyfing, $0\le -\alpha \langle g,z \rangle-\bar{\alpha}\langle z,g \rangle+\alpha\bar{\alpha}$. Now, for $\alpha=\langle z,g \rangle$ we get $0\le -\left |\langle z,g\rangle\right |^2$, so $$\langle z,g\rangle=\langle f-g_0,g\rangle=0.$$

Comment: Why do we need such $\alpha$ scaling argument? Can't we do this without that?

Comment: If you want, you can start wtiting $\langle z,z\rangle=\left\|{z}\right\|^2\le\left\|{z-\langle z,g \rangle g}\right\|^2$

Comment: Can you tell me what makes you think such $\alpha$?

Comment: Simply: it works.

Comment: Not simply? It's important for me to get upgraded on my math skill.

Answer (score 0):

By a well known theorem there are $P:H\to S$, $Q\to S^{\perp}$ linear maps such that for all $x\in H,$ $x=Px+Qx$ (unique decomposition) and $Px$, $Qx$ the closet elements to $S$ and $S^{\perp}$ respectively. In our case, $$f=Pf+Qf=g_0+\underbrace{Qf}_{\in S^{\perp}}\Rightarrow f-g_0\in S^{\perp}\Rightarrow\langle f-g_0,g\rangle=0,\quad \forall  g\in S.$$

Comment: Oh thanks. But can we prove it by not using the decomposition? I want to get the goal only from my start point.

Comment: @kayak look at my new approach.

Answer (score 0):

Ok from what you wrote I guess we are supposing that $g_0$ is existing.
If such an element exists, then let's take $y$ in S, and $\theta$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Then, $\theta y + g_0$ is an element of the subspace S, and it's further from f than $g_0$ (this is how we defined $g_0$ after all).
So,
$$||f-g_0||^2 \le ||f-g_0-\theta y||^2$$

By rewriting RHS:

$$||f-g_0||^2 \le ||f-g_0||^2 - 2 \theta(f-g_0,y)+\theta^2||y||^2$$

Then you only have to subtract $||f-g_0||^2$ from each side. You then have:

$$\theta(f-g_0, y)+\theta^2||y||^2\ge 0$$ and this for any $\theta$. The only way to ensure this is to have $(f-g_0,y)=0$ for any y in S.

Comment: Could you prove it from the point I started?

Comment: Corrected it. But I think a scalar parameter is needed.

Comment: Why is it needed? I'm really curious about it.